# Does every camp become a part of your faction if you clear it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just wondering because I recently started playing

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the Civil War questline, then yes, as you clear out Forts, each will become occupied by your chosen faction and will remain occupied for the rest of the game. Not all forts or encampments may be cleared during the quest line, however, and some may remain occupied by the hostile faction until

> a peace agreement is reached.

Additionally, if you occupy a city during the Civil War questline, all the guards will change from "CityName Guard" to your faction's soldiers. This is true for each city other than the two capitals of the factions, Winterhold and Solitude.